# how get overlapping offset and create subset from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring

I have a text and a array of blocks which have object which represent offset from starting and end offset of string. i want to make unique block from this and aggregate based on largest offset. a sample is below.

```
let text =
  "announcing improvements to the GitHub Actions “New Workflow” experience. Now, when you want to create";
```

```
let blocks = [
  {
    word: "GitHub",
    start: "31",
    end: "37",
  },
  {
    word: "Now",
    start: "73",
    end: "76",
  },
  {
    word: "GitHub Actions",
    start: "31",
    end: "45",
  },
  {
    word: "the GitHub Actions “New Workflow” experience.",
    start: "27",
    end: "72",
  },
];
```

in above example *"the GitHub Actions “New Workflow” experience."* is largest word which have *"GitHub"* and *"GitHub Actions"* as sub set so in out start end offset set will with largest one and other two will be part of split

---

**Expected output**

```
let finalSplit = [
  {
    start: "73",
    end: "76",
    splits: [
      {
        word: "Now",
        start: "73",
        end: "76",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    start: "27",
    end: "72",
    splits: [
      {
        word: "GitHub Actions",
        start: "31",
        end: "45",
      },
      {
        word: "the GitHub Actions “New Workflow” experience.",
        start: "27",
        end: "72",
      },
      {
        word: "GitHub",
        start: "31",
        end: "37",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Add some code...

Answer (score 2):

You can use grouping by hash approach:

```js
const blocks = [{word: "GitHub", start: "31", end: "37"},{word: "Now", start: "73", end: "76"},{word: "GitHub Actions", start: "31", end: "45"},{word: "the GitHub Actions “New Workflow” experience.", start: "27", end: "72"}];

const reduced = blocks.reduce((acc, block) => {
    const [{ start, end }] = blocks
      .filter((s) => (s.start <= block.start) && (s.end >= block.end))
      .sort((s1, s2) => (s2.end - s2.start) - (s1.end - s1.start));
      
    const hash = `${start}-${end}`;
    acc[hash] = acc[hash]
      ? { ...acc[hash], splits: [...acc[hash].splits, block] }
      : { start, end, splits: [block] };
    
    return acc;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(reduced);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: adding comments help to other people to understand line by line Thanks!